# How to count number of Button clicks in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm building an android application and I need to count how many times a button is clicked within a specific time the display it in another page, any help?

Comment: Add your code snippet

Answer (score 10):

try this way, first declare global variable on your activity class file like below :

```
int clickcount=0;
```

after add click event to button and increment value clickcount variable like below code:

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickcount=clickcount+1;
        if(clickcount==1)
        {
            //first time clicked to do this
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked first time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //check how many times clicked and so on 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked count is"+clickcount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your work but what if I have another page that should display how many times it was clicked so I need database because all my project contains buttons and I have an info page that displays how many each button is clicked and at what time

Comment: @CaroleMattar What do you mean by **another page**? You can always use _SharedPreferences_ for keeping track of number of button clicks, even after you exit the app. It is much more easier to use than using database.

Comment: my application doesn't have a single text field , it is full of activities where each activity has  about 8 buttons  and there is a page to let the care taker know what has been clicked and how many times  and the date   if you please provide me with a source code that can help me out  to display the number of each button that has been clicked on this activity

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @sandipon is fine.But global variables could be destroyed,you can use SharedPreferences to store the value in case you'd like to make it persistent.

Comment: could you please give me a complete code on what u mean and as I said I need to display how many times a button is clicked on another activity  with its time and date

Comment: Okay.just give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

you can add clicks into `List<Long/*timestamp*/>` and read values later, you can store your clicks into list and cleanup this list by timer. you can... you have many ways to do this. and save values into your database or preferences, if you need.