# how to Tack all the Button click event

Tags: android, onclick, tracking

How to count number of click perform all the android apps?

I try on all click listener to increment click count and save to share-preferance,

But it to lengthy and time consume

Any one have idea to easy way to track button click event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count number of Button clicks in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755327/how-to-count-number-of-button-clicks-in-android) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112791/how-to-increment-a-counter-inside-an-onclick-view-event

Comment: Just use a `int counter`  with `counter++` each time on ``onClick()`

Comment: No man, I already try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112791/how-to-increment-a-counter-inside-an-onclick-view-event and task,      and i write in description, i want to track hall the application click event,, its to lengthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that extends Application. Create a static counter there and update the counter in every click listener of your app. Further you can save this counter in shared preference in your Application class' onStop method and get it in onStart method.